# JSON array object not deleting upon update

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb

I have this JSON-object:

```
{
"_id": "5f73756944cbbd0fecb3bc70",
"name": "Kragerø Grand Prix 2020",
"description": "Kragerø Sjakklubb inviterer nok en gang til Kragerø GP. Dette for tiende gang! Det er satt en grense på 100 spillere, så meld deg på før det er for sent!",
"time": "90 minutter + 30 sekunder pr. trekk",
"group": "Individuell turnering",
"place": "Kragerø Sportell",
"date": "14. - 17. okt 20",
"organizer": "Kragerø Sjakklubb",
"arbiter": "FA Hans Jørgen Hoem",
"price": "550 kr for FIDE under 2150. IM/GM gratis samt WFM.",
"players": [
    "Bastian T. Pedersen"
]
```

}

When I try to **update** via a PUT request **without** the "players" object array like this:

```
{
"_id": "5f73756944cbbd0fecb3bc70",
"name": "Kragerø Grand Prix 2020",
"description": "Kragerø Sjakklubb inviterer nok en gang til Kragerø GP. Dette for tiende gang! Det er satt en grense på 100 spillere, så meld deg på før det er for sent!",
"time": "90 minutter + 30 sekunder pr. trekk",
"group": "Individuell turnering",
"place": "Kragerø Sportell",
"date": "14. - 17. okt 20",
"organizer": "Kragerø Sjakklubb",
"arbiter": "FA Hans Jørgen Hoem",
"price": "550 kr for FIDE under 2150. IM/GM gratis samt WFM."
```

}

The "players" array **doesn't** seem to get removed. Because when I do a GET request to the **same id**, I still get this response:

```
{
"_id": "5f73756944cbbd0fecb3bc70",
"name": "Kragerø Grand Prix 2020",
"description": "Kragerø Sjakklubb inviterer nok en gang til Kragerø GP. Dette for tiende gang! Det er satt en grense på 100 spillere, så meld deg på før det er for sent!",
"time": "90 minutter + 30 sekunder pr. trekk",
"group": "Individuell turnering",
"place": "Kragerø Sportell",
"date": "14. - 17. okt 20",
"organizer": "Kragerø Sjakklubb",
"arbiter": "FA Hans Jørgen Hoem",
"price": "550 kr for FIDE under 2150. IM/GM gratis samt WFM.",
"players": [
    "Bastian T. Pedersen"
]
```

}

For reference, I use **MongoDB** to store this data and **Postman** to retrieve the data. Any help?

Comment: We need to see your MongDb code

Comment: Show your code.